# How to make autocomplete field of material UI required?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have tried a couple of ways in order to make the material UI's autocomplete field of type required but I am not getting the behavior that I wanted. I had encapsulated my field inside react hook form `<Controller/>` yet no luck. I want to trigger message 'Field is mandatory' on submit when nothing is added to the field.

Below is the code snippet, I have not removed comments so that it becomes a bit easier for others to understand the approach that I had followed earlier -

```
  <Controller
        name="displayName"
        as={
          <Autocomplete 
                  value={lists}
                  multiple
                  fullWidth
                  size="small"
                  limitTags={1}
                  id="multiple-limit-lists"
                  options={moduleList}
                  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.displayName}
                  renderInput={(params,props) => {
                   return (
                      <div>
                        <div className="container">
                          <TextValidator {...params} variant="outlined" label="Display Name*" className="Display Text" 
                            name="displayName"  id="outlined-multiline-static" 
                            placeholder="Enter Display-Name" size="small"
        onChange={handleDisplay}
         // validators={['required']} this and below line does throw a validation but the problem is this validation stays on the screen when user selects something in the autocomplete field which is wrong.
        // errorMessages={['This field is required']} 
        // withRequiredValidator
        
                            />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )
                  }}
                  />
        }
        // onChange={handleDisplay}
        control={control}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        // required
        // defaultValue={options[0]}
        />
        <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="displayName" message="This is required" />
```

Comment: it probably returns empty object as default, why not use `validate` function.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following logic to get it worked. Though this might not be the best solution but works.

```
<Autocomplete 
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            label={value.length === 0 ? title : title + " *"} //handle required mark(*) on label 
            required={value.length === 0}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Comment: Great! Work for me. Tks!

Answer (score 8):

I tried using the built in required in textfield for autocomplete, and it works like a charm. Maybe you can use this as a reference.

```
<Autocomplete
    renderInput={(params) => {
        <TextField {...params} required />
    }
    // Other codes
/>
```

Comment: The issue is that the "multiple" option of MUI Autocomplete doesn't play nice with the "required" attribute. With "multiple" enabled, the Autocomplete stores values in an array, but the HTML input element backing the control will have a string value, "", and thus failing the "required" attribute validation.

Comment: I have putted it in renderInput Field but the problem is that in AutoComplete if it set to multiple. Then it will raise error even if we selected the TextField because their may be other option in text field which is not selected at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are rendering `<TextValidator>`, you should apply mandatory(required) attribute to that component not on `<AutomComplete>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your **Material UI** version is **v5**

```
           <TextField
              {...params}
              required
              label="Tags"
              value={value}
              InputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps,
                required: value.length === 0,
              }}
            />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).